# Why is my Share dropdown is from the side but not from bottom?

Tags: android

I have been searching around for the answer but couldn't find. Below is in my current app.
[image: Share Dropdown Image]

How can I fix it to slide from bottom ? Is it because of the version that I am using ? I believe sliding from the bottom is the default animation when shared button is pressed because it works that way in all the apps.

Below is my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    //CardView
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}
```

Below is how I add it to menu_main.xml

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share"
        app:actionProviderClass=
            "android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

Edit:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = title_maps + ". Download now at Google Play Store!";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share Subject");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        //set the sharing intent
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sharingIntent);
```

Comment: That is default menu style that you can see when you click on your menu item and the bottom one, share pops up when you give you data to some Intent example `Intent send = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(String "Hello");
        send.setData(uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(send, "Send mail..."));`

Comment: @shadygoneinsane my intent does have some data but it just doesn't slide from bottom.

Comment: Can you post your code which you are using to pass your data to an Intent to open a chooser from bottom !

Comment: @shadygoneinsane edited above